Is there a difference between a full node running bitcoin daemon, or bitcoin-qt?
I have a full node running in my office off it's own static IP.  I'd like it to contribute as much as possible to the network, and share as many block with as many peers as possible.  (We have a 1Gbit line, it's limited to 100Mbit, or 1/10th of our bandwidth.)
It's currently running the bitcoin-qt GUI client, and has a fully synced copy of the blockchain.
Are there any differences between the Command-Line daemon and the GUI?  Are their any configuration changes I can make to allow the instance to connect to more peers, or to be more 'generous' sharing blocks?

bitcoin-qt is just bitcoind with a GUI, they are the same in every other regard.
There really isn't much need for "generous" nodes, but some things you can do is to make sure other nodes can connect to you (this might require port forwarding), increase maxconnections and enable your node to run over Tor and I2P. Also make sure to run a recent version of Bitcoin Core that includes the v2 encrypted transport protocol.

Where do I set the 'maxconnections' parameter?  In the console, or a config file?

Like any config option, either in the bitcoin.conf file or as a command line parameter.
